# Java program using arrays simple coding for project

Tags: java, arrays, project

I just want "Jan Expenditure" to appear however only expenditure comes out. How do I do it? Jan is from my monthsArrays. Is there anything missing?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Project {

static int choice;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    {   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("***************Expenditure***************");
        System.out.println("1)Enter monthly expenses");
        System.out.println("2)Display detailed expenditure by month");
        System.out.println("3)Quick glance at monthly expenses");
        System.out.println("4)Exit");
        System.out.println("Please select your choice <1-3>:");
        choice = input.nextInt();


        switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            int count = 0;
            String[] monthsArray = { "", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May",
                    "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" };
            System.out.println("*******************************************");
            System.out.println("\t\t\t\t");
            System.out.print("Enter month <1 for Jan - 12 for Dec>:");
            int month = input.nextInt();
            for (int i=0; i < monthsArray.length; i++)
            String monthChoice = monthsArray[month - 1];
            System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
            System.out.println(monthChoice + "expenditure (max 10 items)");
```

This is the output i'm getting currently

*********Expenditure***************

1)Enter monthly expenses

2)Display detailed expenditure by month

3)Quick glance at monthly expenses

4)Exit

Please select your choice <1-3>: 1

---

Enter month <1 for Jan - 12 for Dec>:1

---

expenditure (max 10 items)

Enter item 1:

As you can see the array "Jan" is not appearing.

Comment: The part where the user have to choose which month it is for. I used an array for the months. However when the "user" chooses 1. "Jan" doesnt appear. my desired output would be: "Jan Expenditure" but its only "expenditure that appears

Comment: This is not how stackoverflow works. You need to attempt this first and post here if you encounter a problem or some "unknown" that had not already been answered here before. Plus, asking for "possible ways to code this" is dangerously close to asking for others to do your work for you.

Comment: @user3249322 Could you post your code?

Comment: @Teeg I already started on this project there are just some parts i cant seem to figured out. Look I just started learning programming & could really use some help. if you don't wanna help thats alright. Thanks.

Comment: @user3249322 Could you post please a compilable example? You're missing braces in this one (in your for per example).

Comment: @Teeg i have pasted my code. thats only part of what I have done.

Comment: @JoshM there's part of the coding i have done. is that better?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From the looks of your `monthsArray`, the first element is a blank string. Remember that arrays are zero-based, and you asked your user for a month between 1 and 12 (which is fine, because nobody thinks of January as month 0, right?). Later in your code, you do this:

```
String monthChoice = monthsArray[month - 1];
```

However, your array actually contains 13 elements, because you added that blank space, so in your case, you're actually safe to simply use the unaltered `month` index, like so:

```
String monthChoice = monthsArray[month];
```

OR, get rid of the empty string at the beginning of the array, and leave your `monthChoice` line as is (depends on how your implementation is supposed to work. That is purely your choice).

**Some side notes:**

You are presently declaring your `monthArray` in the body of the switch statement, which is unnecessary. It would be better to declare it at the top of the method, OR even better, as a constant in the class, like so:

```
private static final String[] monthsArray = { "", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" };
```

Also, this line:

```
for (int i=0; i < monthsArray.length; i++)
```

is useless. I don't know whether this is part of an unfinished solution, however all it is doing is repeating the statement that immediately follows it, which as as far as I can tell, is unnecessary. Basically it is the same as this:

```
for (int i=0; i < monthsArray.length; i++){
    String monthChoice = monthsArray[month - 1];
}
```

So you should be safe to get rid of it.

Comment: Thank you! I apologize for any misunderstanding earlier on. I'm just a beginner in programming & I was just really desperate for help as I have to show my tutor my project and how its coming along, tomorrow morning. I have already made changes & it works now!

Comment: @cjmalacaman No problem at all. Being a beginner is perfectly cool, we all had to start somewhere. Just remember the best way to get assistance (especially on this site) is to be as specific as possible about the problem you're having. Best of luck in your endeavours (and future stackoverflow-ing). Also, don't forget to upvote good / helpful answers, and "accept" the answer that helped you the most (by clicking the green checkmark to the left of the answer).

Comment: yes! no problem. This website will definitely help me a lot. hope to get help from you as well in my future questions cause i really like your detailed answer

Answer (score 0):

You have a typical +/-1 error in your code.

Your monthsArray has an empty String at position 0 and you take the displayed String from month -1. Simply entering 2 and getting "Jan expenditure (max 10 items)" as a result should have been a good hint.